# Oracle query in Java Spring MVC does not work properly

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, ibatis

```
<select id="BBSManageDAO.selectBbsSchdulManageList" parameterClass="BoardVO" resultMap="schdulProgramList">
<![CDATA[
SELECT NTT_ID, BBS_ID, NTT_NO, NTT_SJ, SUBSTR(NTT_CN,1,100) NTT_CN, CATEGORY, FRST_REGIST_PNTTM, NTCE_BGNDE, NTCE_ENDDE
,FIELD1, EVN_END_DATE, FIELD2, TELL_NO, USE_AT
FROM TN_BBS A
WHERE 1=1
AND A.USE_AT = 'Y'
AND (
BBS_ID = 'education01_main' or BBS_ID = 'course01_main' or
BBS_ID = 'feestival01_main' or BBS_ID = 'reading01_main'
    )
 ]]>
<isNotEmpty property="searchCondition2">
<isEqual property="searchCondition2" compareValue="DAILY" prepend="AND">
<![CDATA[ #searchSdate# >= FIELD1 AND #searchSdate# <= EVN_END_DATE ]]>
</isEqual>
isEqual property="searchCondition2" compareValue="WEEK" prepend="AND">
<![CDATA[ (#searchBgnDe# <= FIELD1 AND #searchEndDe# >= FIELD1) OR (#searchBgnDe# <= EVN_END_DATE AND #searchEndDe# >= EVN_END_DATE) OR (#searchBgnDe# >= FIELD1 AND #searchEndDe# <= EVN_END_DATE) AND USE_AT='Y']]>
</isEqual>
</isNotEmpty>
<![CDATA[   
 ORDER BY FIELD1 ASC
]]>
</select>
```

This is the part of the code inside of my `SQL_Oracle.xml`

This query is about selecting some articles of event if the article fulfill the condition(condition is about date).

I have two APIs. One is daily and the other one is weekly.

In daily query user send a specific date(`#searchSdate#`) as a parameter and DB search event which is going on that day.

In weekly user send a week so they give to the server the start date of the week and end date of the week and send back events going on that week.

The problem is though I wrote

```
WHERE 1=1  
AND A.USE_AT = 'Y'
```

When I use the `WEEK` search they send me the events with 'N' USE_AT data.
I don't care if `DAILY` send me the same data. But they don't
Finally when I added **AND `USE_AT='Y`'** to end of the `WEEK` search they worked.

But still I don't know why maybe there is some error of my ibatis grammer.

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue with your query above. Try modifying the query with or to brakets around all included in OR comparison: like below

```
( (#searchBgnDe# <= FIELD1 AND #searchEndDe# >= FIELD1) 
 OR (#searchBgnDe# <= EVN_END_DATE AND #searchEndDe# >= EVN_END_DATE) 
 OR (#searchBgnDe# >= FIELD1 AND #searchEndDe# <= EVN_END_DATE) )
 AND USE_AT='Y'
```

Also your `SQL_Oracle.xml` file has xml issue as the second `isEqual` is not tagged properly